# Connecting to SAP HANA installed from AWS marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, hana

I have managed to install SAP BW HANA installation from AWS Marketplace ([instruction](https://s3.amazonaws.com/c2e-marketplace/Documents/CoreToEdge_SAP_Systems_AMIs_Platform-BW%E2%88%954HANA_SLES_HANA_DEPLOYMENT_GUIDE_v1.0.pdf)), but unfortunatelly I am not able to connect to this instance. The doc from amazon gives the following sheet about ABAP object:

[image]

After starting the database with HDB start, I try to connect with following commands:

```
hdbsql -i 00 -u DDIC -p <password>
hdbsql -i 00 -u SYSTEM -p <password>
```

But I keep having same errors:

> -10709: Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=111:Connection refused (localhost:30015))

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you remotely logged on (ssh?) to the HANA server of this system? Otherwise you will need to provide a hostname paramter, e.g. `hdbsql -n <hostname> -i 00 -u DDIC -p <password>`

Comment: yes I am logged remotely. I have also tried passing `-n localhost` and it didn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

Check services status by this command, HDB Status. Is all services running ?